# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object error from aws eb after deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I am having this error after deploying to aws elastic beanstalk
the code is normally functional on my localhost.

can anyone please help me?

This is from my controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $location = DB::table('branches')->where('codename', $request->location)->first();

        $uId = $request->user_id;

            // User::updateOrCreate(['id' => $uId], ['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'active' => $request->active]);
            User::where('id', '=', $uId)->update(['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'active' => $request->active, 'loc_code' => $request->location, 'usercode' => $location->id, 'loc_name' => $location->name]);
            $msg = 'User data is updated successfully';
            return redirect()->route('admin.user-list')->with('success', $msg);
        }
```

this is from my blade:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#edit-repair', function() {
        var repair_id = $(this).data('id');
        $.get('/repair/' + repair_id + '/edit', function(data) {
            $('#userCrudModal').html("Edit Repair");
            $('#btn-update').val("Update");
            $('#btn-save').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#crud-modal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
            $('#crud-modal').modal('show');
            $('#joborder').val(data.joborder);
            $('#createdby').val(data.createdBy);
            $('#location').val(data.activeLoc);
            $('#fname').val(data.fname);
            $('#lname').val(data.lname);
            $('#address').val(data.address);
            $('#contact').val(data.contact);
            $('#imei').val(data.imei);
            $('#model').val(data.model);
            $('#color').val(data.color);
            $('#pass').val(data.pass);
            $('#repairtype').val(data.repairType);
            $('#remarks').val(data.remarks);
            $('#status').val(data.status);
            $('#origin').val(data.origin);
            $('#usercode').val(data.usercode);

        })
    });
```

I tried the updateorcreate but still the same problem appear.

Comment: Try `dd($location)` first to check whether it's available.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the `first` method can return `null`, you have to check for this

Comment: Maybe your local database has some data in the branches table, but your production database doesn't have any. So your $location variable is null on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: you have my thanks. i have a problem in my `.ebextesion` then the branches table is not working properly and need to run migrate again. you saved me.

Comment: Great, happy it helped. I'll write it into an answer and please accept it so it can help others too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the $location variable. It looks your local database has some data in the "branches" table, but your production database doesn't have.

So, your $location variable is null when read from the database in the Elastic Beanstalk server. Make sure your production database working and has all the data.